# Angular: Lazy-Loading Module not calling InjectionToken factory

Tags: angular

I am trying to provide the `APP_BASE_HREF` injection token in a Lazy-Loading Module,
however, the factory method is not called at all.

Here https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Angular-Lazy-Injection/branches you can find the corresponding minimal project, with two separated branches:

- **app-provider-root** (working custom APP_BASE_HREF)
- **lazy-provider-root** (not working custom APP_BASE_HREF)

You can also try the two branches on StackBlitz:

- https://stackblitz.com/github/MaurizioCasciano/Angular-Lazy-Injection/tree/app-provider-root
- https://stackblitz.com/github/MaurizioCasciano/Angular-Lazy-Injection/tree/lazy-provider-root

If I move the same code snippet to the static AppModule it gets called as expected.

```
 providers: [
   {
     provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
     useFactory: appBaseHrefFactory
   }
]


export function appBaseHrefFactory() {
  console.log("APP MODULE window.location.pathname: " + window.location.pathname);

  return window.location.pathname;
}
```

How can I force the APP_BASE_HREF to be provided also from the Lazy-Loading module?

**Update**

If I inject the value in the module constructor, the factory method gets called, but the value is not picked up by the imported module/service.

```
export class RemoteModule {
  constructor(@Inject(APP_BASE_HREF) private apipBaseHref: string) {
    console.log("Remote APP BASE HREF: " + appBaseHref);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try adding `multi: true` to the provided definition.

Comment: I tried, but it is still not calling the factory method.

Comment: It sounds like you're just missing the route ref in your provide with `useValue` as such `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/your/base/href'}` which I'll just leave as a comment since there's no reproducible example to debug.

Comment: The value has to be determined at runtime, therefore I use a factory instead of a static path.

Comment: Do you want to use several base hrefs?

Comment: The value of APP_BASE_HREF is picked up only once at Router initialization

Comment: @yurzui so the only place where I can initialize it is where the RouterModule.forRoot() is called? Can't it be re-initialized from another module?
This is the case of multiple remote modules (with webpack module federation) and each one has its own routing. Therefore I need a way to isolate the different apps' routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide any token, like `APP_BASE_HREF`, or any other in the current module, - this token will be available only for this module and its children. Not for any other.

To solve your case you can add some kind of state, for example with service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BaseHrefValueService extends BehaviorSubject<string> {
}
```

Create reusable provider, just to DRY:

```
export const APP_BASE_HREF_PROVIDER = {
  provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
  useFactory: (service) => {
    if (!service.value) {
      service.next(window.location.pathname);
    }

    return service.value;
  },
  deps: [BaseHrefValueService]
}
```

And then inject it in any lazy modules:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [APP_BASE_HREF_PROVIDER],
})
export class YourModule {}
```

Comment: Could you explain how this is different from my approach? I mean, it still has to go via the factory method that doesn't get called in the lazy-loaded module. Maybe it is because the RouterModule.forRoot() is called/initialized in the app module so it looks for the InjectionToken only there? I don't think I can move it anywhere else.

Comment: This factory method called in lazy module if you provide `APP_BASE_HREF_PROVIDER`. This way you can provide one value through the project, and even from lazy module to others. Try it.

Comment: I tried it and started a blank project on GitHub but it is not working. The APP_BASE_HREF is only provided in the App-Module, not the Lazy-Module. https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Angular-Lazy-Injection/branches

Comment: Check example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jpqd5t

Comment: I did, you are configuring the providers for the AppModule not the LazyModule.
Check here https://angular-ivy-3ingzv.stackblitz.io providers in the LazyModule are not working. Maybe it has to do with the scope of the Router?